# Getting Error while starting glassfish server

Tags: glassfish, java, java-6, java-5

when I am starting glass fish server through command prompt I am getting an 
error. I am using **jdk 1.5** and **jdk1.6** also. Due to java version am I getting that error or any other reason.
I am using **two tomcat server** also that port no is **8080 and 8081.**
For **glass fish-domain** purpose I am using **4545** port number.

```
Error starting domain mydomain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
```

Before it died, it produced the following output:

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:133)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: What is the error, can you share the exception trace?

Comment: We can't really help you unless we know which error you're getting. It could be anything really...

Comment: Error starting domain mydomain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

Comment: at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:12

Comment: 4)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at

Comment: sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Instrument
ationImpl.java:133)
Exception in thread "main"

Answer (score 1):

This is the important bit.

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

It means that the class loader does not understand the version number of one of the ".class" files that it is trying to load.

The most likely explanation is that you are trying to load classes that have been compiled on a Java 7 development platform on an earlier (e.g. Java 5 or Java 6) JRE / JVM installation.  You either need to upgrade your execution platform to Java 7 (**best option**), or downgrade your development platform to Java 5 or Java 6 (or whatever you are using).

Note that *both* Java 5 and Java 6 have reached "end of life", and there will not be any more patch releases available ... unless you take out an Oracle Java support contract.

Comment: ya sir now server has started but inside the browser login page is not giving response..

Comment: Means that page is keep on loading.. login page is not coming.

Comment: That means you have now fixed your first problem and run into the next one.